# What is the correct workbox caching strategy for a PWA that doesn't need to function offline?

Tags: caching, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I have built a fuel station locator PWA that used Google Maps API to return stores and their info and fuel prices around a users location. Whilst I know a PWA must have offline functionality - in my case I have just built a simple offline page that displays a message and checks for reconnection as there isn't much point in caching non live information.

I am unsure though what my caching strategy should be considering I am only serving 'online' users? My current cache size is around 200MB according to chrome dev tools which seems really high, I am not caching more than around 30 CSS files and ±20 JS files and a handful of small PNGs. I have excluded external google JS by using RegExp to filter out assets that arent part of example.com domain.

Here is my current serviceworker:

```
const JS_CACHE = "javascript";
const STYLE_CACHE = "stylesheets";
const IMAGE_CACHE = "images";
const FONT_CACHE = "fonts";

self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === "SKIP_WAITING") {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
new RegExp('.*\.example.com/.*\.js$'),
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: JS_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 20,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
new RegExp('.*\.example.com/.*\.css$'),
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: STYLE_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 30,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
new RegExp('.*\.example.com/wp-content/.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$'),
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: IMAGE_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 15,
      }),
    ],
  })
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  ({event}) => event.request.destination === 'font',
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: FONT_CACHE,
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 15,
      }),
    ],
  })
);


//  Creat offline page cache.
workbox.core.setCacheNameDetails({
    prefix: 'offline-cache'
});



// Incrementing OFFLINE_VERSION will kick off the install event and force
// previously cached resources to be updated from the network.
const OFFLINE_VERSION = 1.1;
const CACHE_NAME = "offline-page";
const OFFLINE_URL = "offline.html";

self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    (async () => {
      const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
      await cache.add(new Request(OFFLINE_URL, { cache: "reload" }));
    })()
  );
  self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    (async () => {
      if ("navigationPreload" in self.registration) {
        await self.registration.navigationPreload.enable();
      }
    })()
  );
  self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  if (event.request.mode === "navigate") {
    event.respondWith(
      (async () => {
        try {
          const preloadResponse = await event.preloadResponse;
          if (preloadResponse) {
            return preloadResponse;
          }

          const networkResponse = await fetch(event.request);
          return networkResponse;
        } catch (error) {
         
          console.log("Fetch failed; returning offline page instead.", error);

          const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
          const cachedResponse = await cache.match(OFFLINE_URL);
          return cachedResponse;
        }
      })()
    );
  }
});
```

If I am only serving 'online' users do I need to cache anything at all - wouldn't the browser cache the assets anyway? Does over-caching slow down things as the serviceworker has to intercept every request?

Comment: Do  you have solution for this ? I need to serve online users only